# Using restrictions of a $\sigma$-algebra to find the $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $M$ be a manifold and let $(U_k)_{k\ge 1}$ be a countable cover. Let $\mathcal X$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $M$ such that $\mathcal X|_{U_k}=\mathcal B_{U_k}$, where $\mathcal X|_{U_k}:=\{i_{k}^{-1}(E):E\in\mathcal X\}$, $\mathcal B_{U_k}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $U_k$, and $i_k:X_k\to X$ is the inclusion.
> Prove that $\mathcal X=\mathcal B_M$ where $\mathcal B_M$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $M$.

**Attempt**

I can show that for a topological space $M$ and its open subset $N$, we have $\mathcal B_N=\mathcal B_M|_{N}$. Thus I know that $\mathcal B_M$ satisfies the conditions. I want to prove the uniqueness, but I only prove that $\mathcal X\subset \mathcal B_M$:

For $E\in\mathcal X$,
we have $E=\bigcup_{k}(U_k\cap E)=\bigcup_{k} i_{k}^{-1}(E)$;
since $i_{k}^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal X|_{U_k}=\mathcal B_{U_k}\subset \mathcal B_M$,
we have $E\in \mathcal B_M$. Hence $\mathcal X\subset \mathcal B_M$.

How to show that  $\mathcal B_M\subset \mathcal X$?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The claim is false.  For example, let $M=\mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}$, $U_0,U_1$ the two copies of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{X}=p_1^*\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ where $p_1\colon M\to\mathbb{R}$ is the projection onto the first factor (so every member of $\mathcal{X}$ is $B\times\{0,1\}$ for some $B\in\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$).  You need some conditions to make sure $\mathcal{B}_{U_k}\subseteq\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for your reply! What if the manifold is connected? We usually default that manifold is connected

Comment: Essentially the same counterexample: $M=S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with every $U_k$ connected open intervals of less than half the total circumference, and $\mathcal{X}$ only consists of symmetric sets under $x\to -x$.  Or you can do with $\mathbb{R}$, pulling back from $S^1\cong\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $U_k=(k/4,(k+2)/4)$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$...